# Unable to set cache control header for any static resources (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, caching

I am trying to set cache control for any static resources (images, js, css) in my website. I am using Spring 4 (with Spring Security) and Tomcat 8 server.

I already tried to set ExpiryFilter in my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>ExpiresByType image</param-name>
       <param-value>access plus 2 weeks</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>ExpiresByType text/css</param-name>
       <param-value>access plus 2 weeks</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>ExpiresByType text/javascript</param-name>
       <param-value>access plus 2 weeks</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But since the ExpiresFilter not working, I tried to set MVC Resources with the cache-period:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/,classpath:/resources/" cache-period="2592000" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

But it isnt working either.

I also tried to check whether the filter-mapping in my web.xml is working, but it turns out it did not filters any of images/js/css type, but filtered my html file. My static files are kept inside webapp/resources folder, whether my html file is inside webapp/WEB-INF/jsp file.

I also add this in my spring security config:

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"></http>
```

Is there anything I miss?

Thank you.

Comment: How this was fixed. I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I enabled logging of the filters of tomcat by org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter.level = FINE in logging.properties of tomcat.

When the filter got initialized the following log got printed in the catalina log :

Filter initialized with configuration ExpiresFilter[excludedResponseStatusCode=[304], default=null, byType={text/css=ExpiresConfiguration
[startingPoint=ACCESS_TIME, duration=[10 MINUTE]], application/javascript=ExpiresConfiguration[startingPoint=ACCESS_TIME, duration=[10 MINUTE]]
, image=ExpiresConfiguration[startingPoint=ACCESS_TIME, duration=[10 MINUTE]]}]

You can see that all the http responses with status 304 will get excluded for setting the cache control parameters.

I configured the tomcat filter and my resources were cached. This I can confirm by the filter logs :

org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter onBeforeWriteResponseBody
FINE: Request "/static/img/home/phone_icon2.png" with response status "200" content-type "image/png", set expiration date 1/31/17 11:59 AM
Jan 31, 2017 11:49:30 AM org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter getExpirationDate
FINE: Use ExpiresConfiguration[startingPoint=ACCESS_TIME, duration=[10 MINUTE]] matching "image" for content-type "image/png" returns 1/31/17 11:59 AM
Jan 31, 2017 11:49:30 AM org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter onBeforeWriteResponseBody
FINE: Request "/static/img/home/bgimage.png" with response status "200" content-type "image/png", set expiration date 1/31/17 11:59 AM
Jan 31, 2017 11:49:30 AM org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter getExpirationDate
FINE: Use ExpiresConfiguration[startingPoint=ACCESS_TIME, duration=[10 MINUTE]] matching "image" for content-type "image/png" returns 1/31/17 11:59 AM

I would advice you to first enable logging [Reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/filters/ExpiresFilter.html)